# Why are du -h / du / df / df -h not refreshing when extracting a large file

Tags: filesystems, mount, kernel, disk-usage

I am running tar in the background, eg:

```
tar xfvz large_file.tar.gz    &
```

It does extract my file, but when I then launch `du -h`, `du`, `df` or `df -h`, the output remains the same, and I have to wait few minutes for it to refresh.

Is there any workaround? That's not really a problem, I am asking this for my own Unix culture about `du` & `df` & so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the data has not actually been written to disk yet but is still in the page cache ("dirty pages"). Check with

```
grep Dirty /proc/meminfo
```

You can try to run `sync` before `df`/`du`. That should force any data in the page cache to be written to disk.